# In Pure Data how to keyup, keydown, and while keydown?

Tags: keypress, keydown, keyup, long-press, puredata

I'm trying to setup a little midi keyboard (using my computer's keyboard) in Pure Data. It works this way:

```
press a key > send a note_on on midi channel
stop pressing a key > send a note_off on midi channel
```

The problem is, that when you keep a key pressed the `[key]` object generates a series of inputs instead of a single (long) one. This stops the (desired) note from playing (since the original input stops, after ~500ms) and re-starts playing the note many times in a row.

I've already tried `[change]`, `[timer]`+`[moses]` and other non-solutions, I'm looking for a better implementation of `[key]` that can handle long key-presses

I'm looking for something that does `[key]`'s job but that can handle a long-press, if I long-press a key with `[key]` for more than a second it does something like:
key....(1 sec passes)...keyup.key.keyup.key.keyup. and it goes on and on...

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that your Operating System(!) generates repeated key events if you keep pressing the key.

### solution

so the simple solution is to tell your OS to suppress repeated key events.

### workaround

the more complicated workaround is to keep track of the current state of the given key and suppress duplicate keydowns. this is most easily done if you only track a single key (rather than all at once):

e.g. an abstraction [keypress 97] that will detect keypresses of <kbd>a</kbd> (ascii 97):

```
[key]        [keyup]
|            |
[select $1]  [select $1]
|            |
[t b b]      |
|     [stop( |
|     |      |
|     +----- |
|           \|
|            [del 50]
|            |
[1(          [0(
|            |
| -----------+
|/
[change]
|
[outlet]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `[keyname]`:

- http://en.flossmanuals.net/pure-data/sensors/game-controllers/

Here is an example patch that will write to an array when multiple keys are pressed. It should be possible to use this as a polyphonic input. I think then using [tabread] and iterating the array index number would indicate whether a key is pressed or not (the index should match the ascii/key number):

```
#N canvas 800 301 544 205 10;
#X obj 23 23 keyname;
#X symbolatom 89 40 10 0 0 0 - - -;
#X floatatom 23 46 5 0 0 0 - - -;
#X obj 181 18 key;
#X floatatom 181 46 3 0 0 0 - - -;
#X floatatom 220 44 3 0 0 0 - - -;
#X obj 220 18 keyup;
#X obj 44 87 pack float symbol float float;
#X obj 67 117 print;
#X obj 46 151 tabwrite array1;
#N canvas 0 0 450 300 (subpatch) 0;
#X array array1 256 float 1;
#A 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
#X coords 0 1.2 255 0 256 100 1 0 0;
#X restore 277 33 graph;
#X connect 0 0 2 0;
#X connect 0 1 1 0;
#X connect 1 0 7 1;
#X connect 2 0 7 0;
#X connect 2 0 9 0;
#X connect 3 0 4 0;
#X connect 4 0 7 2;
#X connect 4 0 9 1;
#X connect 5 0 7 3;
#X connect 5 0 9 1;
#X connect 6 0 5 0;
#X connect 7 0 8 0;
```

Example with <kbd>a + g</kbd> pressed at the same time:

[image]

After pressing <kbd>s</kbd>:

[image: after pressing 's']

While <kbd>a</kbd>:

[image: while a]

After pressing <kbd>a</kbd>:

[image: after a]

I was able to find something here as well: http://puredata.hurleur.com/sujet-3718-pdkb-basic-virtual-midi-keyboard

zipfile: http://puredata.hurleur.com/attachment.php?item=1635

Looks neat, not sure if it functions.

Comment: First link in this answer is dead (*404 Not Found*). Please check. Thanks.